# fgets() returns false even though file is not empty

Tags: php, file, fgets

I have a form from which I save the given input into a textfile,
but I have trouble reading from the saved file:

```
while(!feof($fileNotizen)) {
$rawLine = fgets($fileNotizen);
if($rawLine==false) {
  echo "An error occured while reading the file"; 
}
```

`$rawLine` seems to be always false, even though I use this function before, to fill the textfile:

```
function addToTable($notizFile) {
 fwrite($notizFile, $_POST["vorname"]." ".$_POST["nachname"]."#");
 $date = date(DATE_RFC850);
 fwrite($notizFile, $date."#");
 fwrite($notizFile, $_POST["notiz"].PHP_EOL);   
}
```

And after I submit the form and get the error message, if I check the textfile, everything is there, so the function works correctly.

If it is of value, I open the file with this command:

```
$fileNotizen = fopen("notizen.txt", "a+");
```

Could the problem be that the pointer is already at the end of the file and thus returns false?

Answer (score 2):

```
$fileNotizen = fopen("notizen.txt", "a+");
```

**`a+` opens for read/write but places file pointer AT THE END**. So you must [**fseek**()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to the beginning first or look into [**fopen**() flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and choose more wisely based on your needs.

Use `fseek($fileNotizen, 0, SEEK_SET);` to rewind the file.

Comment: This seems to be what I need, but adding this did no change to the output, I also tried `rewind($fileNotizen)` without result.

Comment: @Big_Chair Use `fseek($fileNotizen, 0, SEEK_SET);` to rewind the file. And make sure the file is actually opened `if($fileNotizen)`. And use `__DIR__` to use an absolute path.

Comment: It seems my problem must be caused by something else, because this did not seem to help either. 
Thank you for your help though!

Comment: might want to also change your test to `if($rawLine===false)` you might be getting a falsy value from the file (empty line)

Answer (score 0):

To read/get content of the file try this function:

```
    function read_file($file_name) {
        if (is_readable($file_name)) {
            $handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $content .= fgets($handle); 
            }
            return !empty($content) ? $content : "Empty file..";
        } else {
            return "This file is not readable.";
        }
    }
```

and if you want to see content of the file displayed on separate lines then use `<pre></pre>` tag like this:

```
echo "<pre>" . read_file("notizen.txt") . "</pre>";
```

and if you want to write/add content to the file then try this function:

```
    function write_file($file_name, $content) {
        if (file_exists($file_name) && is_writable($file_name)) {
            $handle = fopen($file_name, "a");
            fwrite($handle, $content . "\n");
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$content = "{$_POST["vorname"]} {$_POST["nachname"]}#" . date(DATE_RFC850) . "#{$_POST["notiz"]}";
write_file("notizen.txt", $content);
```